# How to validate with before insert trigger in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I've been searching on the web how to use "before trigger" in sqlite. I know properly on using "after trigger". I found the one that said that "before trigger" was used to validate before any changes made to database (insert/updat row in table). To clear the expression, I wrote a trigger in which type is before and event is insert to validate mark before inserting. 
My trigger is

```
create trigger mark_insert before insert on exam
when mark<=50
begin
insert into exam(mark) values(50);
end;
```

Maybe it is wrong trigger. So, could you please point me out the errors in it?
I want to check the mark whether it is less than or equal 50. If so, I want to insert default value(in this case, 50). I'm not much familiar with sql and trigger and starting to learn.

My exam table has following columns,

```
id(pk) | subject | mark
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to raise an error on invalid data, do this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_validate_mark BEFORE INSERT ON exam
WHEN mark<=50
BEGIN
  SELECT RAISE(ABORT,'Mark must be at least 50.');
END;
```

If you just want to fix the data, do this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_min_mark AFTER INSERT ON exam
WHEN mark<=50
BEGIN
  UPDATE exam
  SET mark=50
  WHERE id = new.id;
END;
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But I got this error : no such column mark.
Is it due to raise()? Can you explain about raise function?
 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `raise` is how you generate an error within a trigger.  http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Comment: After the SELECT statement, `;` is required.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to check the mark whether it is less than or equal 50

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_min_mark AFTER INSERT ON exam
WHEN New.mark<=50
BEGIN
  UPDATE exam SET mark=50 WHERE id = New.id;
END
```

Be carefull you in the `when` statement you must specify `New.ColumnName`

Answer (score 4):

What about ensuring it in the table definition?

```
CREATE TABLE exam (
  ...
  CHECK(mark<=50)
);
```